# Notify python orion/quantumleap subscription changes

Tags: python, fiware, fiware-orion

Is there any way to get notified in python when a Quantumleap o Orion subscription fires for a changed value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've dockerized the [nickjj web server](https://github.com/nickjj/webserver), switched the `bind_host` to `0.0.0.0` as specified in the documentation, and exposed the port `8008:8008` in `docker-compose`.

[nickjj Python web server](https://github.com/nickjj/webserver):

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from sys import argv

BIND_HOST = '0.0.0.0'
PORT = 8008

class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.write_response(b'')

    def do_POST(self):
        content_length = int(self.headers.get('content-length', 0))
        body = self.rfile.read(content_length)

        self.write_response(body)

    def write_response(self, content):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(content)

        print(self.headers)
        print(content.decode('utf-8'))


if len(argv) > 1:
    arg = argv[1].split(':')
    BIND_HOST = arg[0]
    PORT = int(arg[1])

print(f'Listening on http://{BIND_HOST}:{PORT}\n')

httpd = HTTPServer((BIND_HOST, PORT), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Dockerfile to build the web server service:

```
# Build the service from the base image
FROM python:3.9.16-alpine3.17

# During building, run the following commands to install dependecies
RUN apk add --no-cache openssl-dev curl-dev
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
# RUN pip install pycurl crate requests

# Set the work directory
WORKDIR /webserver

# Copy in the continer the following files
COPY ./webserver ./webserver

# Run this command at startup
CMD ["python","-u","webserver", "webserver:8008"]
```

docker-compose configuration for the web server, with `curl` for debug:

```
webserver:
  image: webserver
  stdin_open: true # docker run -i
  tty: true        # docker run -t
  container_name: 'webserver'
  ports:
    - "8008:8008"
  networks:
    - default
```

I've provisioned the relative subscription in Orion:

```
curl -iX POST \
    'http://localhost:1026/v2/subscriptions/' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -H 'fiware-service: opcua_car' \
    -H 'fiware-servicepath: /demo' \
    -d '{
  "description": "Subscriptions for Python webserver",
  "subject": {
    "entities": [
      {
        "idPattern": ".*",
        "type": "PLC"
      }
    ],
    "condition": {
      "attrs": [
        "processStatus"
      ]
    }
  },
  "notification": {
    "http": {
      "url": "http://webserver:8008/"
    },
    "attrs": [
      "processStatus"
    ],
    "metadata": [
      "dateCreated",
      "dateModified"
    ]
  },
  "throttling": 1
}'
```

And I finally get my subscription notifications in Python.

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest way to receive HTTP notifications coming from [Orion](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion) is to setup an http server to listen those notifications (http requests) within you Python code. For example by using [Flask](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flask_(web_framework)).

Best.

Comment: Yeah, either you implement n Python, C,node,js or any other language, the notification is sent as an HTTP request (unless you prefer MQTT, which is also an option).  Your implementation just needs to be prepared to receive the information.

Comment: Did you have any code related to Orion I can take as reference?

Comment: I've added the code that I've ended up at the moment, if you have any hint on why in not working would be much appreciated.